# Unwanted div wrapping after appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Hello beloved SO users,

I have come with yet another question. And hopefully you can help me out.

**Background information:**

I am working on a grid that can store items by dragging and dropping them on to corresponding grid fields. When the grid is re-calculated (f.e. by switching to a different week number) the matching objects for that week get appended to my grid row like such:

```
//Create orderItem to place into the DOM
var div = "<div class='draggable orderItem stored' id='" + orderId + "'>" +
                    "<a href='#/order/" + orderId + "'>" + orderId + "</a>" +
                    "</div>";

//Append div to the end of the gridRow
var gridRow = "div #" + planningList[plannedItem].get("resource").cid + ".eventRow";
$(div).appendTo(gridRow);
```

The above code (as expected) appends the newly created DIV item 'next' to my grid at the end of the row. My DOM also looks like expexted. The eventRow contains both the grid fields with information such as dates, as well as the *appended orders* which are placed by use of Javascript positioning:

```
<div id="1886" class="eventRow">
    <div class="gridRow"></div>
    <div id="c303" class="draggable orderItem stored" style="width: 90px; position: relative; left: -680px; top: 0px;"></div>
    <div id="c308" class="draggable orderItem stored" style="width: 180px; position: relative; left: -775px; top: 20px;"></div>
    <div id="c312" class="draggable orderItem stored" style="width: 180px; position: relative; left: -960px; top: 40px;"></div>
</div>
```

**The problem:**

So, if everything get's appended correctly and the top and left position keep changing well depending on the amount of items placed in the eventRow then what's the problem?

There is none untill ten or so items are added to a eventRow. After that suddenly the next item to be added gets drawn way out of the expected position. I took a while to examine what happend and the best I could figure out was that (do to float left in my CSS) the items get appended after the row besides each other *even if* they are repositioned thereafter.

So when the total amount of div items reaches a collective width that is greater then the width of the screen, the browser wraps around the DIV and starts the next element on a new row within the DIV. This is what messes my positioning up, since it neatly keeps adding an increasing left value to the row.

My CSS is as following:

```
div.eventRow {
    clear: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: visible;
 }
 div.orderItem{
    float:left;
    text-align: center;   
    margin: 1px 5px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0 5px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 60px;    
}
div.orderItem.stored{ /* has been rendered on the grid */
    width:90px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**TLDR;**

I am running out of space to append new DIV's to within the row. When this occurs the web browser wraps the newly added code to a new line which messes up my positioning. Since this can happen quicker at smaller resolution screens I wish to stop this wrapping from occurring or to find a decent alternative to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried three possible solutions:

1. Only make the DIV's one pixel in width or change the display type to invisible AFTER appending to the grid.
2. Remove the float left causing all order to align underneath each other.
3. **Change the way the position left is calculated.**

The first two fail because a minimum width on the DIV does not effect the inline text.  Also when repositioned and re-sized after placing the problem would still occur. Removing the float left made top-based positioning (multiple-items underneath each other in a grid row) very difficult.

so the final solution was to find out *when* the DIV-wrapping happened. This is done by comparing the expected position (assuming the order would be placed behind the previous one) with the actual position. If this does not match you know the parent DIV is wrapping the item.